# No puedo redireccionar con PHP en MVC

Tags: php, html, mvc, headers

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto MVC con PHP, pero tengo un problema y es que al intentar hacer una redirección desde una acción de un controlador, me sale el siguiente error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\invexpress.mvc\views\layout\header.php:83) in C:\xampp\htdocs\invexpress.mvc\controllers\MenuController.php on line 26

Por más que busco el error no lo encuentro.

En esta vista, llamada **menu.php**, es en la que estoy haciendo la redirección con una etiqueta `<a>`, en la cual pongo como enlace el controlador **menu** y la acción **redirecciontest**, la cual me arroja el error antes mencionado:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 espacio-columnas">

      <!--AQUÍ SE ESTÁ HACIENDO LA PRUEBA DE REDIRECCIÓN-->
      <a href="<?=base_url ?>menu/redirecciontest">
      <!--AQUÍ SE ESTÁ HACIENDO LA PRUEBA DE REDIRECCIÓN-->

        <img src="<?=base_url ?>assets/img/flag_planos.gif" width="129" height="165" alt="PLANOS">
      </a>
      <p></p>
      <p class="FAMILIA-doble">PRUEBA REDIRECCION</p>
    </div>
```

Aquí dejo el código del controlador **MenuController.php**:

```
<?php

class menuController{
    public function index(){
        Utils::isLogged();
        require_once 'views/menu/menu.php';
    }

    public function submenu(){
        Utils::isLogged();
        //header('Location:'.base_url);
        
        if(isset($_GET['art'])){
            $art = $_GET['art'];
            if (file_exists('views/menu/'.$art.'.php')) {
                require_once 'views/menu/'.$art.'.php';
            }else{
                require_once 'views/menu/error.php';
            }
        }else{
            header('Location:'.base_url);
        }
    }

    /**ESTA ES LA ACCIÓN DE PRUEBA PARA REDIRECCIÓN**/
    public function redirecciontest(){
        header('Location:'.base_url);
    }
    /**ESTA ES LA ACCIÓN DE PRUEBA PARA REDIRECCIÓN**/
}
```

Aquí dejo el **index.php**:

```
<?php 

session_name('invexpress');
session_start();

require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'config/database.php';
require_once 'config/parameters.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['identity'])){
  header("Location: ".base_url."login.php");
}

require_once 'helpers/utils.php';
require_once 'views/layout/header.php';


function show_error(){
  $error = new errorController();
  $error->index();
}

if(isset($_GET['controller'])){
  $nombre_controlador = $_GET['controller'].'Controller';

}elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
  $nombre_controlador = controller_default;
  
}else{
  show_error();
  exit();
}

if(class_exists($nombre_controlador)){  
  $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();
  
  if(isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET['action'])){
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $controlador->$action();
  }elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action_default = action_default;
    $controlador->$action_default();
  }else{
    show_error();
  }
}else{
  show_error();
}


require_once 'views/layout/footer.php';
```

Y por si también lo necesitan está el **header.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  

  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <!--compartido-->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=base_url ?>assets/img/favico.ico" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?=base_url ?>assets/img/favicon.png">
  <!--compartido-->

</head>
<body>


  <!--solo de header-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?=base_url ?>assets/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?=base_url ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/default-passive-events"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.3.2/sweetalert2.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:600|Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?=base_url ?>assets/css/stilo_inventario2019.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="<?=base_url ?>assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--solo de header-->


  <!--loader del header-->
  <div class="loader" style="cursor: wait"></div>
  <!--loader del header-->    

    <!--advertencia cierre de sesion header-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="session-expire-warning-modal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">                  
            <h4 class="modal-title">Advertencia de cierre de sesión</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Tu sesión expirará en <span id="seconds-timer"></span> segundos. ¿Te gustaría mantener la sesión abierta?
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnOk" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px;  background-color: #428bca; color: #FFF;">Sí</button>
            <button id="btnLogoutNow" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px;  background-color: #428bca; color: #FFF;">Cerrar sesión ahora</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--advertencia cierre de sesion header-->


    <!--sesion expirada solo header-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="session-expired-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Sesión expirada</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Tu sesión ha expirado.
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnExpiredOk" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; background-color: #428bca; color: #FFF;">Ok</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--sesion expirada solo header-->    
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav navbar-right" style="position: fixed; right: 30px; top: 80px; z-index: 3;">
      <!-- href original del carrito: ../pedido/inventory_pedido_STRECH.php -->
      <a href="../pedido/inventory_pedido_STRECH.php" id="about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>

        <span class="badge label-warning"><?php echo "0"; //echo $cantidadped;?></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php" style="padding:0px"><img src="<?=base_url ?>assets/img/acerocid_inventa-xpress.png" width=230/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="<?=base_url ?>">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Planos
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_rollos_.php">Rollos de Lámina</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_cintas_.php">Cintas</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_lam-lisa-placa_.php">Lámina Lisa & Placa</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_lam-acanalada.php">Lámina Acanalada Rectangular</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_lam-acanalada_ondu.php">Lámina Acanalada Ondulada</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_lam-acanalada_onduR.php">Lámina Acanalada Ondulada Reforzada</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_teja.php">Teja de Lámina</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_caballete.php">Caballete</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_losacero25.php">Losacero Sección 25</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_losacero15.php">Losacero Sección 15</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_RD91.php">RD 91.5</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_planos_RN100.php">RN 100/35</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tubería
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_tubos_de-cercas.php"> Cerca</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_tubos_conduccion.php">Conducción</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_tubos_conduit.php">Tubo Conduit Rígido</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_tubos_mecanico.php">Mecánica</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_tubos_industrial.php">Tubo Industrial</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_tubos_petro.php">Tubo Petrolero</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Largos
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_largos_alambron.php">Alambrón</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_largos_alambre-galva.php">Alambre Galvanizado</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_largos_alambre-plastic.php">Alambre Plastificado</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_largos_alambre-pulido.php">Alambre Pulido</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_largos_alambre-recocido.php">Alambre Recocido</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_largos_clavos.php">Clavos</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Perfiles
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_ptr.php">PTR</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_hss_square.php">HSS Rectangular & Cuadrado</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_hss_redondos.php">HSS Redondo</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_polin.php">Polín</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_tablaroca_.php">Tablaroca</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_riel.php">Riel</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_carrilera.php">Carrilera</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_cortina-flex.php">Perfil Cortina Flex</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_duela.php">Perfil Duela</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_tablero-ang.php">Perfil Tablero Angular</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_tablero-recta.php">Perfil Tablero Rectangular</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_bastidor.php">Bastidor para Puertas</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_manguete.php">Perfil Manguete de Puerta</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_marco-simple.php">Perfil Marco para Puertas</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_marco-doble.php">Perfil Marco Tope Doble</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_pasamanos.php">Perfil Pasamanos</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_ventanas_.php">Perfiles para Ventana</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_perfil_canaleta.php">Canaleta</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Mallas
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_mallas_galvanizada.php">Ciclónica Galvanizada</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_mallas_plastificada.php">Ciclónica Plastificada</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_mallas_aber-special.php">Ciclónica Abertura Especial</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_mallas_graduada.php">Graduada (Borreguera)</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_mallas_multimalla.php">Multimalla Ferretera</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_mallas_acces_.php">Accesorios de Cercas</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_mallas_cintaprivacidad.php">Cintilla de Privacidad</a></li>          
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Concercid
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_concercid_arpon.php">Concertina Arpón</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_concercid_industrial.php">Concertina Industrial</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_concercid_residencial.php">Concertina Residencial</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Flexcid
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_flexcid_moflero.php">Tubo Moflero Flexible</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_flexcid_conduit.php">Tubo Conduit Flexible</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Casta Brava
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!--<li><a href="../inicio/fam_castabrava_pua.php">Alambre de Púas</a></li>-->
          <!--<li><a href="../inicio/">Alambre de Púas Tradicional</a></li>-->
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_castabrava_pua-alta.php">Alambre de Púas Alta Resistencia</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_castabrava_pua-tradicion.php">Alambre de Púas Tradicional</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_castabrava_grapa.php">Grapa</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_castabrava_posteT.php">Poste Ganadero "T"</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_castabrava_clip-posteT.php">Clip para Poste "T"</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Invernadero
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_riel.php">Riel Invernadero</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_zigzag.php">Alambre Zig-Zag</a></li>
          <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_abraza.php">Abrazadera para Invernadero</a></li>
    <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_canalon.php">Canalón para Invernadero</a></li>
    <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_ancla.php">Ancla/Hélice para Macrotunel</a></li>
    <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_cuerno.php">Cuerno para Macrotunel</a></li>
    <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_estaca.php">Estaca para Macrotunel</a></li>   
      <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_caballet-reten-cruz.php">Caballete-Travesaño</a></li>
      <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_caballet-reten-cruz.php">Retenida</a></li>
      <li><a href="../inicio/fam_inverna_caballet-reten-cruz.php">Cruceta</a></li>          
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="<?=base_url ?>controllers/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<!--minipanel de nombre de usuario y empresa del header-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row col-lg-offset-4 text-right">
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body col-lg-11">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
        </span> <?=$_SESSION['identity']->name; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> <?=$_SESSION['identity']->empresa; ?>

         &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#config"><span class="datos_user"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Configurar</span></a>  

 <?php 
//declaras una var que se usara en el arrray 
    $tipousuario=$_SESSION['identity']->level_id;
    if ($tipousuario=='1') {
      echo ' &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; 
     <a href="admin_user_list.php"><span class="datos_user">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
      </span> Usuarios</span></a> ';

    }
    else if ($tipousuario=='2') {
      
    }
    ?>

            <!--Solo ver admin-->
      
         <hr>
          <div class="row" style="margin-top:-10px;">
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-8">
            
              </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4" id="clockbox">
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--minipanel de nombre de usuario y empresa del header-->


<!-- init session para timeout del header -->
<script>
  //initSessionMonitor();
</script>
<!-- init session para timeout del header -->

<!-- Modal de cambio de usuario y nombre header -->
<div id="config" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Configurar Cuenta</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p style="color:#F60">Cambiar Nombre de Usuario</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nuevo Usuario:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name2" style="display: none;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuariocambiar">            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Contraseña Actual:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="recipient-name2" style="display: none; ">            
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="currentpassuser">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <p style="color:#F60">Cambiar Contraseña</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Contraseña Actual:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="currentpasspass">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nueva Contraseña:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passcambiar">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Confirmar Contraseña:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passcambiarconfirmar">
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_user" id="id_user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>">
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal de cambio de usuario y nombre header -->



  <div id="content">
```

Las posibles soluciones, como verificar que no haya espacios antes del **<?** y eso, ya lo verifiqué y no encontré ningún error. Y puede que sea algo sencillo pero no lo logro encontrar.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

EDIT: Lo que comenta masterguru, de borrar la linea 83 donde me marca el error del header que contiene:

```
<span class="badge label-warning"><?php echo "0"; //echo $cantidadped;?></span></a>
```

No resuelve el problema, ya que luego me indicará el error en la siguiente apertura de php. Por ejemplo así:

**(output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\invexpress.mvc\views\layout\header.php:91)**

Donde la línea tiene escrito:
`<a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php" style="padding:0px"><img src="<?=base_url ?>assets/img/acerocid_inventa-xpress.png" width=230/></a>`

donde tenemos `<?=base_url ?>`. Y si llego a quitar ese también, me mandará al siguiente y así hasta llegar a quitar todas las aperturas de PHP hacia abajo.

Pero una vez quitadas, el mensaje de error ahora indicará la ultima linea del **header.php** tenga o no alguna apertura de php.

Comment: El error te indica que el problema lo tienes en la linea 83 de header.php, donde aparece esto: `<span class="badge label-warning"><?php echo "0"; //echo $cantidadped;?></span></a>` ... prueba quitando el comentario a ver si así se soluciona o quitalo todo temporalmente a ver donde peta despues

Comment: Eso lo intenté, pero después me lo indica en las demás aperturas php siguientes, así hasta que después de quitarlas, indica el final del header.php

Comment: Vale, eso es porque ya incluyes el header.php de saque en el index.php con esto: `require_once 'views/layout/header.php';` y deduzco que aunque el header tenga solo un espacio en blanco tambien te pasará.  Debes incluir el header.php despues de la acción del controller para que eso no ocurra (o dentro del controller si se cumplen las condiciones, pero no en el index.php si luego quieres redirigir algo).

Comment: La cuestión es muy simple: **antes de los `header` no debe salir nada, pero nada por pantalla**. Comprendido eso, vuelve a pensar la forma en que tienes organizado tu código y el orden en que vas cargando las cosas. Si te has decidido por MVC es porque quieres tener tu código ordenado, reutilizar código, etc. Pues bien, repiensa el código y verás que, en el flujo, estás incluyendo salidas antes de los `header`. Tus salidas deberían ser recogidas o incluidas en la vista y es allí donde debes poner los `header`, una vez tengas a mano todo lo que va a salir por pantalla.

Comment: Revisé y revisé el código y no encontré ninguna salida antes del header, pero encontré otra solución (no se si sea la más óptima, pero fue la que funcionó), y fue poner ```ob_start();``` al inicio del index.php y ```ob_end_flush();``` después de cada redirección que se realice en algún controlador. Creo que de momento lo dejaré así. Gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: La salida era la que te dije antes. Cuando haces un `require_once 'views/layout/header.php';` y este contiene HTML ya estas imprimiendo a la salida, por lo tanto, cuando después llamas al controlador y este a la función header(); ya es demasiado tarde.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Enviar datos de formulario con Modal para editar usuario (UPDATE) PHP y MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/532238/enviar-datos-de-formulario-con-modal-para-editar-usuario-update-php-y-mysql)