# Enviar datos de formulario con Modal para editar usuario (UPDATE) PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, php7

tengo un formulario con Modal para editar usuarios, mismo que se capturan desde la base de datos, quiero usar 2 archivos, el primero llamado **usuarios.php** y el otro llamado **editar_usuario.php** que contiene únicamente el codigo de **UPDATE**, sin embargo, no se como hacer para enviar esos datos y poder realizar el update

este es mi codigo del archivo **usuarios.php**

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['user'];


if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>Usuarios</title>
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Waves Effect Css -->
    <link href="plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation Css -->
    <link href="plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- JQuery DataTable Css -->
    <link href="plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- AdminBSB Themes. You can choose a theme from css/themes instead of get all themes -->
    <link href="css/themes/all-themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="theme-red">
    <!-- Page Loader -->
    <div class="page-loader-wrapper">
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="preloader">
                <div class="spinner-layer pl-red">
                    <div class="circle-clipper left">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="circle-clipper right">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Porfavor Espere...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Aca incluyo el menu de navegacion y header -->  
  <?php include 'includes/HeadMenu.php';   ?>

    <section class="content">

 <!-- Widgets -->
 <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-5 col-xs-10">
                    <div class="info-box bg-orange hover-expand-effect">
                        <div class="icon">
                        <a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddModal" href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">Nuevo Usuario</div>
                            <div class="number count-to"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </div>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            
            <!-- Basic Examples -->
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>
                                Usuarios
                            </h2>
                            <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Something else here</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Usuario</th>
                                            <th>Fecha de Creacion</th>
                                            <th>Accion</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   
                        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> <?php echo $row['user']  ?> </td>
                                            <td> <?php echo $row['fecha_creacion']  ?>  </td>
                                            <td> <a href=" eliminar_usuario.php?id_user= <?php echo $row['id_user']   ?> " onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro que deseas eliminar el registro?');">
                                                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                
                                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModal" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('idEdit').value = <?=$row['id_user']?>;document.getElementById('userEdit').value = '<?=$row['user']?>'">
                                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- #END# Basic Examples -->
            
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Modal para Ingresar -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="AddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Agregar Nuevo Usuario</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">      
                <form action="agregar_usuario.php" id="ingresar" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" minlength="6" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    

                    <input type="submit" name="ingresar_usuario" Value="Registrar" class="btn btn-primary">

                </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    <!-- Modal para Modificar -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Editar Usuario</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        
                        <form action="editar_usuario.php?id_user=<?php echo $_REQUEST["id_user"]; ?>" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="idEdit" value="">
                       
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                        <input id="userEdit" type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required value="" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="modificar_usuario" id="modificar_usuario" Value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-primary">

                </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




    <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Select Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

    <!-- Slimscroll Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>

    <!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/node-waves/waves.js"></script>

    <!-- Jquery DataTable Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Js -->
    <script src="js/admin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pages/tables/jquery-datatable.js"></script>

    <!-- Demo Js -->
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
<?php
}else{
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

y este es mi codigo del archivo **editar_usuario.php**

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

//Modificar usuario

if (isset($_POST['modificar_usuario'])) {
    $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
    $user= $_POST['user'];
  
    $query = "UPDATE usuarios set user = '".$user."' WHERE id_user=".$_REQUEST["id_user"];"";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Task Updated Successfully';
    $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'warning';
    header('Location: usuarios.php');
  }

?>
```

Ya únicamente me faltaría realizar el UPDATE sin embargo no se como hacerlo, si alguien me ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuando con tu anterior pregunta, y procurando no corromper la respuesta de la misma, yo lo haria así:

Donde pones esto:

```
<form action="editar_usuario.php?id_user=<?php echo $_REQUEST["id_user"]; ?>" method="POST">
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
<form action="editar_usuario.php" method="POST">
```

pues el dato **id_user** por *GET* no lo vas a necesitar, además que no te irá bien porque el `$_REQUEST["id_user"]` seguramente no existirá o no será con el valor que le corresponde realmente.

Luego, en **editar_usuario.php** donde pone esto:

```
$id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
$id_user = $_POST['id'];
```

pues es el **name=** que le corresponde realmente tal como está tu código HTML.

Y por último, donde pone esto:

```
$query = "UPDATE usuarios set user = '".$user."' WHERE id_user=".$_REQUEST["id_user"];"";
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
$query = "UPDATE usuarios set user = '".$user."' WHERE id_user=".$id_user;
```

porque ahora, gracias al cambio anterior, sí que tendrás bien recogido el dato en la variable **$id_user** y la puedes usar directamente (además lo del _$*REQUEST["id_user"]* no te funcionaba porque en el HTML tambien lo recuperabas mal, tal como he indicado en el primer cambio de esta respuesta).

Comprueba ahora si todo te funciona y lo comentas.

Comment: Te lo agradezco infinitamente, funciono perfecto